# Counting the number of items in a file using java

Tags: java

I have a text file:

```
2|BATH BENCH|19.00
20|ORANGE BELL|1.42
04|BOILER ONION|1.78
```

I need to get the number of items which is 3 here using JAVA. This is my code:

```
int Flag=0;
    File file = new File("/Users/a0r01ox/Documents/costl-tablet-automation/src/ItemUPC/ItemUPC.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        Flag=Flag+1;
    }
```

It is going in an infinite loop.
Can someone please help? Thank you.

Comment: You keep asking whether there is a line available to be read, but you never consume that line.

Comment: Add a  `sc.nextLine()` to move on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get the next line to avoid an endless loop.

```
int Flag = 0;
File file = new File("/Users/a0r01ox/Documents/costl-tablet-automation/src/ItemUPC/ItemUPC.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    sc.nextLine();
    Flag++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
  Flag=Flag+1;
  String line = sc.nextLine(); //Do whatever with line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code you have written

```
int Flag=0;
    File file = new File("/Users/a0r01ox/Documents/costl-tablet-automation/src/ItemUPC/ItemUPC.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) { // this line is just checking whether there is next line or not.
        Flag=Flag+1;
    }
```

When you write `while (sc.hasNextLine()){}` it check whether there is nextLine or not.
eg 
line 1 : abcdefg
line 2: hijklmnop

here your code will just be on `line 1` and keep telling you that `yes` there is a `nextLine`.

Whereas when you write

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
sc.nextLine();
Flag++;
}
```

`Scanner` will `read` the `line 1` and then because of `sc.nextLine()` it will go to `line 2` and then when `sc.hasNextLine()` is checked it gives `false`.